# Error: Cannot find module './api' (Hyperledger composer)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

After installing Hyperledger Composer cli from this [page](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html), I tried to call composer command but got this error:

```
module.js:549
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './api'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report/index.js:3:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I used this command to install Hyperledger Composer:

```
npm install --unsafe-perm -g composer-cli
```

May I know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my case I installed composer-cli in global `/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli` and I met the same problem. I don't know what's wrong but I tried:

1. Change directory into the composer-cli:

   `cd /usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli`
2. **Reinstall** node report module, **locally inside** the composer-cli:

   `sudo npm install node-report --unsafe-perm`

Notice I don't put `-g` param in `sudo npm install` to make the installation local to the composer-cli itself.

The `node-report` will run `make` with `g++` to compile something (which for some reason was not run during composer-cli installation) and it just works... Now I can run composer.

For your case set the working directory to `/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli` instead.

Comment: This solves my issue like it is stated in the question. Thank you @chrtian

Answer (score 7):

The answer is

1) **DON'T resort to using root or sudo** (as advised in a comment above) to install Composer npm modules - this causes issues for npm per the [prerequisites](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs) . Instead, follow best practices for npm installs: don't use sudo or root to install Composer - it will always cause issues further down the line. Follow the best practices here https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

2) Have a supported npm version (5.x as of June 2018) per the install [docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs)

3) Install -  then use  - `nvm` to manage your NODE versions - as indicated above Node 8.11.x is supported. For NVM - see https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation - it installs it. Eg. `nvm install v8.11.1`  2) `nvm use 8.11.1` etc

4) If you have already / previously installed Composer modules using sudo or root - remove them using that id using `npm uninstall -g` (ie global), then follow the 'best practices' mentioned above in 1) and follow the [Composer install docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools) to do the Composer modules install - very very straightfoward.

Following these steps - it works every time.

Comment: Using nvm to install resolved this issue for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For me, completely wiping

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli
```

and executing
 `npm install -g composer-cli`

did the job :) (reinstalling node-report didnt work)

Comment: Notice the debug (from the question) `at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report/index.js:3:13)` which is why my answer was about `node-report` as well. Maybe in your case it was not node-report.

Comment: it was node-report in the debug, No idea why the reinstall didn't work